# How Add System.Web Reference To A Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, windows, system.web

I want to use HttpUtility.UrlEncode in a windows form application,
but i can not find System.Web in .NET (Add Reference) area!
How can i add this assembly to my project?
i am using .net 4...

thanks in advance

Comment: What .NET framework version are you targetting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right click on a project -> Properties -> Change Target Framework from **.Net Framework 4 Client Profile** to **.Net Framework 4**

When you remove a **Client Profile** restriction, you will see **System.Web** in .Net (Add Reference) area.

Comment: Worked perfectly. My target framework was 4.5 (not 4.5 client profile). I set it to 4.0 (not 4.0 client profile) simply.