# Add System.Web Reference To A Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, reference, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, system.web

I download a project on [Gitgub](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/Speech/TextToSpeech/Samples-Http/CSharp) Basically is a Console Application. 
But I want to translate this C# Console Application to a Universal Windows App.

I want to use HttpUtility.UrlEncode in a windows 10 universal, but I can not find System.Web in .NET (Add Reference) How can I add this assembly to my project?

```
Error: The "HttpUtility" Does not existin the current context.
```

Im using Visual Studio 2015

I try with this question:
[How Add System.Web Reference To A Windows Form Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668537/how-add-system-web-reference-to-a-windows-form-application)
But doesnt work for the Universal 10 app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you!! apparently this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `System.Web` assembly is a huge monolith that Microsoft themselves seem to be moving away from.

Usually, for any functionality found within `System.Web`, there's a modern equivalent that can be found elsewhere.

In this case, you'd be looking for [`WebUtility.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which is found in the `System.Net` assembly and is listed as supported on the Universal Windows Platform.

Comment: Excellent. WARNING TO ALL: If you use HttpUtility.UrlEncode in a UWP app, and utilize resharper to import and reference `System.Web`, you will likely get the elusive `error 0x80073b0f: Processing Resources failed with error: Duplicate Entry` and `Conflicting values for resource 'System.Design/ClassComments1` errors.

Comment: I would like to note that this solution wonderfully corrects those issues, at least for me.

Comment: What about all of the other functionality in HttpUtility? -- i.e. [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) for example.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 - [`UriExtensions.ParseQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh835079(v=vs.118).aspx)?